# How can I get onBackPressed() while SearchView is activated?

Tags: android, searchview

How can I handle `onBackPressed()` at search mode? I have implemented the search at the `ActionBar`, and I want to handle `onBackPressed()`.

### Edit:

At `MainActivity` I have added this, but it only gets notified when search is closed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_eye).setVisible(true);
    mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_layers).setVisible(true);
    super.onBackPressed();  
};
```

and my listener for search action looks like this:

```
import com.cyrilmottier.polaris.PolarisMapView;

import android.app.SearchManager.OnCancelListener;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.SearchView;

public class SearchListener implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener, SearchView.OnCloseListener, SearchView.OnSuggestionListener, OnClickListener, OnCancelListener{

    private Context mContext;
    private PolarisMapView mMapView;
    private Menu mMenu;
    private SearchView mSearchView;

    public SearchListener(Context c, PolarisMapView mMapView, Menu mMenu, SearchView mSearchView){
        this.setmContext(c);
        this.setmMapView(mMapView);
        this.setmMenu(mMenu);
        this.mSearchView = mSearchView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        if (Constants.searchPlaceNavigate(query, mContext, mMapView))
            return this.onClose();
        return false;
    }

    public Context getmContext() {
        return mContext;
    }

    public void setmContext(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public PolarisMapView getmMapView() {
        return mMapView;
    }

    public void setmMapView(PolarisMapView mMapView) {
        this.mMapView = mMapView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
        String p = mSearchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getCursor().getString(position);
        if(position== 0)
            p = mSearchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getCursor().getString(position*4+1);
        if(p != null)
            if(position== 0)
                Constants.searchPlaceNavigate(mSearchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getCursor().getString(position*4+1), mContext, mMapView);
            else
                Constants.searchPlaceNavigate(mSearchView.getSuggestionsAdapter().getCursor().getString(position), mContext, mMapView);
        return this.onClose();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onClose() {
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_eye).setVisible(true);
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_layers).setVisible(true);
        mMenu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).collapseActionView();
        return true;
    }

    public Menu getmMenu() {
        return mMenu;
    }

    public void setmMenu(Menu mMenu) {
        this.mMenu = mMenu;
    }

    public SearchView getmSearchView() {
        return mSearchView;
    }

    public void setmSearchView(SearchView mSearchView) {
        this.mSearchView = mSearchView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        this.onClose();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        this.onClose();

    }

}
```

Comment: I have updatetd my question:  How can I handle onBackPressed at search mode?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

another way is to listen on the MenuItem for the ActionExpand/Collapse :

```
    MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search);
    searchMenuItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
            // Do whatever you need
            return true; // KEEP IT TO TRUE OR IT DOESN'T OPEN !!
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            // Do whatever you need
            return true; // OR FALSE IF YOU DIDN'T WANT IT TO CLOSE!
        }
    });
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchMenuItem.getActionView();
    ... // Keep doing as you do
```

I think this way is cleaner, as you listen directly on what you want

Thanks to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/actionbarsherlock/l6Xp4UTx5kQ/f8Ly1rgJuGcJ)

Answer (score 20):

for supporting older devices, following code can be used:

```
        MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(searchItem,new MenuItemCompat.OnActionExpandListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
                //Do whatever you want                   
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
                //Do whatever you want
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: @raheel just one question though, my minimum supported API is 14 , then why do I have to still use MenuItemCompat, i read in some other forums that one needs to do it only if min API level is below 14 ! .. However, thanks for this, it worked !

Comment: this is now deprecated can somebody please update the answer

Answer (score 6):

You can extend SearchView and override dispatchKeyEventPreIme:

```
    public class CustomSearchView extends SearchView{
        public CustomSearchView(final Context context) {
            super(context);
            this.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && 
                event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                this.onActionViewCollapsed();
            }
            return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I also call `this.clearFocus()` after `this.onActionViewCollapsed()` else I end up with some weird highlighting elsewhere in the actionBar

Answer (score 4):

same answer as making a custom search view but with listener

```
public class SearchViewer extends SearchView {
    private OnBackPressListener onBackPressListener;
    private boolean isKeyboardVisible;

        public SearchViewer(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public SearchViewer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public SearchViewer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

        private void init() {
            KeyboardUtils.addKeyboardToggleListener((Activity) getContext(), new KeyboardUtils.SoftKeyboardToggleListener() {
                @Override
                public void onToggleSoftKeyboard(boolean isVisible) {
                    SearchViewer.this.isKeyboardVisible = isVisible;
                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow();
            init();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
            KeyboardUtils.removeAllKeyboardToggleListeners();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean dispatchKeyEventPreIme(KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                if (onBackPressListener != null && !isKeyboardVisible)
                    onBackPressListener.backPress();
            }
            return super.dispatchKeyEventPreIme(event);
        }

        public OnBackPressListener getOnBackPressListener() {
            return onBackPressListener;
        }

        public void setOnBackPressListener(OnBackPressListener onBackPressListener) {
            this.onBackPressListener = onBackPressListener;
        }

        public interface OnBackPressListener {
            void backPress();
        }
    }
```

Util class for keyboard visibility, so if keyboard visible back Press will hide it not close the activity

```
public class KeyboardUtils implements ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener {
    private static HashMap<SoftKeyboardToggleListener, KeyboardUtils> sListenerMap = new HashMap<>();
    private SoftKeyboardToggleListener mCallback;
    private View mRootView;
    private float mScreenDensity = 1;
    private KeyboardUtils(Activity act, SoftKeyboardToggleListener listener) {
        mCallback = listener;

        mRootView = ((ViewGroup) act.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
        mRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);

        mScreenDensity = act.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    }

    public static void addKeyboardToggleListener(Activity act, SoftKeyboardToggleListener listener) {
        removeKeyboardToggleListener(listener);

        sListenerMap.put(listener, new KeyboardUtils(act, listener));
    }

    public static void removeKeyboardToggleListener(SoftKeyboardToggleListener listener) {
        if (sListenerMap.containsKey(listener)) {
            KeyboardUtils k = sListenerMap.get(listener);
            k.removeListener();

            sListenerMap.remove(listener);
        }
    }

    public static void removeAllKeyboardToggleListeners() {
        for (SoftKeyboardToggleListener l : sListenerMap.keySet())
            sListenerMap.get(l).removeListener();

        sListenerMap.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        Rect r = new Rect();
        //r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
        mRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

        int heightDiff = mRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);
        float dp = heightDiff / mScreenDensity;

        if (mCallback != null)
            mCallback.onToggleSoftKeyboard(dp > 200);
    }

    private void removeListener() {
        mCallback = null;

        mRootView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
    }

    public interface SoftKeyboardToggleListener {
        void onToggleSoftKeyboard(boolean isVisible);
    }

}
```

sample code:

```
searchView.setOnBackPressListener(new SearchViewer.OnBackPressListener() {
    @Override
    public void backPress() {
        onBackPressed();
    }
});
```

Comment: Helped me when I was using a SearchView in an unconventional way in a DialogFragment completely outside the default ActionBar with setIconifiedByDefault(false);. Cheers!

Comment: This solution helped me also. I was having a problem with onBackPressed called in setOnBackPressListener because the overriden onBackPressed in my activity was called twice. If anyone has this problem, just in dispatchKeyEventPreIme add those lines `if (onBackPressListener != null && !isKeyboardVisible) {
                onBackPressListener.backPress();
                return true;
            }`

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, the key to it was the previous answers from Mr.Ali Imran and from neworld
I have to Override this method:

```
@Override
public void onActionViewCollapsed() {
    //do somethink
    super.onActionViewCollapsed();
}
```

it is called everytime when searchView is closed, so it can handle the backbutton case to.

Comment: This does not answer the question. `onActionViewCollapsed()` will also fire when user pressed "Home" arrow (< to the left of `SearchView`) but did not press the (hardware) BACK button.

Answer (score 2):

You always can extend any views and override listening methods like this:

```
class MySearchView extends SearchView {
  @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); //don't forget call this
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to define a default constructor as well when extending?      public MySearchView(Context context) {
      super(context);
     }

Comment: Yes, you need to define a default constructor, this is obvious. In answer I wrote only actual code for problem solving.

Answer (score 1):

Override this method  might help you

```
 @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: To what I should bind this listener? to mainActivity? because searchview does not have setOnKeyDown() method only setOnKeyListener

Comment: but @Override
 public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 } does not work either

Comment: This not work because: _Called when a key was pressed down and not handled by any of the views inside of the activity_ . But you can extends `SearchView` and overide its own `onKeyDown` method.

Comment: I agree SearchView can be extended to override the onKeyDown(). But how will you cast the SearchView object returned from searchItem.getActionView() to the extended class?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        searchItem.setOnActionExpandListener(new MenuItem.OnActionExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {
             //do something here

              return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {
            //do something here
            
            //YourActivity is acitvity where you define searchview and fragment
            YourActivity.super.onBackPressed();  //remove fragment from backstack

            return true;
        }
    });

    //Any other code

}
```

`onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item)` will run when click up button from `SearchView` or press back button. It will remove fragment from backstack.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code to handle `onBackPressed()` to goto previous activity

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    int id = item.getItemId();
    switch (id){
        case android.R.id.home:
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```