# how to use an extend SearchView in fragment

Tags: android

I want to extend the SearchView class to override the onKeyDown() method. So i do it within my fragment class as below :

```
public class myfragment extends ListFragment{
...
class CustomSearchView extends SearchView{
    public CustomSearchView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }       

    public CustomSearchView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onkeydown", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
...
}
```

Now i want to make use of this extended SearchView in the fragment. But i am not sure how to do that. Since i create the SearchView object using searchItem.getActionView(), is there some way i can cast it to a CustomSearchView object so that the overriden onKeyDown method gets triggered in my fragment?

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    ...

            // Retrieves the system search manager service
            final SearchManager searchManager =
                    (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

            // Retrieves the SearchView from the search menu item
            final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

            // Assign searchable info to SearchView
            searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                    searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

            searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String queryText) {
                    // Nothing needs to happen when the user submits the search string
                    return true;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    ...
                }
            });
```

This question popped up because of the solution mentioned at [How can I get onBackPressed() while SearchView is activated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626756/how-can-i-get-onbackpressed-action-while-searchview-is-activated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast to your custom `SearchView`:

```
final CustomSearchView searchView = (CustomSearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
```

When you declare the `SearchView` you have to declare your own SearchView using full class name in the meny xml file. Also, if you're using support library, you have to declare `http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto` namespace:

No Support Library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
      android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
      android:actionViewClass="com.xxx.ListFragment.CustomSearchView" />
```

Support Library:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:title="@string/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/action_search"
      yourapp:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
      yourapp:actionViewClass="com.xxx.ListFragment.CustomSearchView" />
```

Comment: The menu inflater throws a class not found exception at runtime for the class "com.example.xxx.PhoneContactListFragment.CustomSearchView". I am not sure what i am doing wrong here. I use "android:showAsAction", not "yourapp:showAsAction". Same with "android:actionViewClass". Because if i use "yourapp:..", the editor shows error "No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.example.xxx'"

Comment: You may be right as I was using support library and I think you don't. Use `android` namespace. As for the error, is your class public. Maybe you can put it outside of the fragment class?

Comment: You are right! I am not using the support library, so i use the `android` namespace. Putting the `CustomSearchView` class in it's own java file resolved the error. But the `onKeyDown` is not being triggered at all when i touch the `SearchView` or any character on the soft keyboard. The `onQueryTextLListener`, defined on the search view in the fragment class, does get triggered as expected. But can't understand why `onKeyDown` does not get called at all.

Comment: What is `ActivityContext` that you're using in `onKeyDown`?

Comment: Thats just a variable to hold getActivity(). I have replaced it with getActivity() just now to make it clear.

Comment: It's interesting that the `onKeyDown()` in the  activity class gets called, if i override it.

Comment: Overriding dispatchKeyEventPreIme() instead of onKeyDown() worked, although it gets called twice each time for some reason.