# How can I change the font of Search view suggestion?

Tags: android, searchview

I searched for hours all they suggest is using customized cursor adapter. however I'm using content provider to fill the suggestion and don't have any cursor adapter . I'm able to find AutoCompleteTextView and change the font of the editable text view now, but I want to do the same for the suggestions. What should I do?

Comment: you'll need to Create your own search-view...that will far easier and more customizable

Comment: refere these links 
1.) Create own SearchView : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20643162/how-to-use-an-extend-searchview-in-fragment

2.)For QueryListener : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938952/android-create-custom-searchview-search-action

Answer (score 0):

To change the font of text you have to implement your own `CursorAdapter` and in `bindView()` method get the reference to the `TextView` and apply the font using `TextView.setTypeface()`.